# How to avoid OOM using images in ListView, GridView builders in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-listview, flutter-gridview

I am trying to lazy load Images in any kind of `ListView`, `GridView`, `StaggeredGridView`, `SliverGrid`, `SliverList`, `ScrollablePositionedList` builders.
I am fetching images from network using `Image.network`.

I am also using `ResizeImage` to reduce the memory taken according to devices screen sizes.

The images are put in cache (which is actually not desired) and never cleared from memory when calling `dispose`.

`Image.memory` is actually behaving the same way, keeping references to object and not deleting them when calling `dispose`.

Here is my related [github issue](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/92378).

How can i only keep in memory the visible items in the `ListView` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use :

```
PaintingBinding.instance!.imageCache!.maximumSizeBytes = 1024 * 1024 * 50; // 50MB
```

Which cap the size retained in memory.